# Umbraco v10 .Net 6.0 Unit Testing

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-10

I am trying to write unit tests for Umbraco v10 using .Net 6 for testing the controllers.

The issue I have is with the setup of the `UmbracoContext`. Documentation is limited on the subject. The `UmbracoContext.EnsureContext` is my starting point by passing in mocked dependencies using the Moq framework.

Is there any documentation to support the use of the method? Or should I be looking elsewhere?

I require the `CurrentPage` object to be correctly instantiated from the `UmbracoPageController` by setting the context.